# ifstream struct array into txt file then extract it out as an array is that possible?

Tags: c++

I have a struct array something like this:

```
struct STUDENT{
   int id;
   string name;
   char grade;
};

int main(){
   STUDENT mydata[50];
   for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
     cin >> mydata[i].id;
     cin >> mydata[i].name;
     cin >> mydata[i].grade;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

How do I put this array into txt so it does not lose its format and then how do i obtain it from txt file and put it into the same struct array variable again?

Sample txt file output

```
1 john A
2 marry B
3 rachel C
```

Comment: Clarify "put this array into txt so it does not lose its format".  I don't see any formatting here.

Comment: You can output this data to the file as per a pre-decided format, like separated by spaces or any de-limiting characters. Then read it the same way.

Comment: You need to serialize it.  A simple way would be to write each member of the struct to a file on its own line and then read it back the same way.  You could also do one record per line but you'd need to have some way of handling names with spaces in them, maybe you put that at the end of the line and just assume everything after the first two fields is the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file Output:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
     file << mydata[i].id << " ";
     file << mydata[i].name << " ";
     file << mydata[i].grade << std::endl;
   }
```

And for reading:

```
int i = 0;
while( i < 50 && file >> mydata[i].id >> mydata[i].name >> mydata[i].grade )
    i++;
```

EDIT:

With regards to error checking, one simple approach is that you can check the final value of `i`. If it is less than `50`, then it means that full data is not read and some error has occurred in between.

For a more robust way, you can check out this link for exception handling.http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/

Regarding a for vs while loop, either of them can be used. However a while loop seems more natural and 'readable' in this case. The for option would look something like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 50 && file >> mydata[i].id >> mydata[i].name >> mydata[i].grade; i++) 
{
}
```

**A very subtle but important advantage of using a for loop is that the loop variable `i` is invisible to the outside program. This can be important because in the while loop case it may cause interference.**

Comment: A bit of code to show how to deal with malformed input (at least how to skip it) would be also helpful.

Comment: You mean malformed input from file?

Comment: Yes, from a file, or from `cin`, or whatever. Let's say "input from `std::istream`".

Comment: what about the space in between the columns?

Comment: can I use a for loop to do this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering i got it working but wondering if for example the name part of the data, john, has spaces like, "john smith", will it affect the program when it extracts data out of the txt file?

Comment: @edward the extraction operator skips the spaces by default. If you want to read a name like john smith then I suggest that you have a delimiting character and use getline ().

Comment: thanks, something like this `1|john smith|A` ? can you give me a quick example? thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes std::cin.getline (name, '|');